# How to scrape lat/long from JavaScript code using Scrapy / XPath

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I want to extract the latitude and longitude from this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.DETAILS_PAGE_MAP_GLOBALS = {
        GOOGLE_MAPS_LONGITUDE: 55.4159330979,
        GOOGLE_MAPS_LATITUDE: 25.1549968578
    };
</script>
```

I tried this xpath

```
contains(.//script[@type='text/javascript']/text(), 'window.DETAILS_PAGE_MAP_GLOBALS')
```

I always get `0`. **I know it is referring to false**

my question how could I get the lat and long from that script? I think contains might help but i don't know how

Comment: I edited your question to be broader than just XPath. Feel free to edit further or revert my changes if I changed too much.

Comment: hmm.. I tried XML and the XPath statement above in an [online XPath tester](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html), and it returned `true`.

Comment: @har07 what did you put in the xml field please? the all source of that page? i tried that but i got an error

Comment: I put that `<script>....</script>` you posted in xml input field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions with [Scrapy selectors](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html).

An example straight from the docs:

`sel.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "image")]/text()').re(r'Name:\s*(.*)')`

That way, you can get the data out in one go.

Comment: would you give me an example on the website that i put in the question?

Comment: Sorry, it would be too much work to test (sorry!). If you provide a complete running but failing example, I'll make it work.